# How to convert a time in PST timezone coming from server to client time zone in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I have a middle ware service which is called by a web layer. The middle ware service is hosted in a central server which is having the timezone in PST.

When a request is made to the service the datetime data returned is in PST format which is the server time zone. But I need to have a solution in my web layer to convert this PST time response to the corresponding client machine timezone which can vary across users.

Is there any way in javascript where I can handle this conversion of timezone?

Comment: Did you try using moment.js ? Best time management library out there

Comment: Have the service return a date using UTC time zone. If that can't be done, convert the PST (UTC -0800) to UTC and send that to clients, they are smart enough to work it out. Will the PST machine also observe daylight saving? In that case you'll need to detect PDT (UTC -0700) and convert that when you get it.

Comment: What are you getting, a string? If so, what is the format?

Comment: im moment.js library they different functions for working with timezone. http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: @RobG the datetime value is coming as a string like "2015-12-01T05:02:00"  for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you **know** the offset is PST (UTC -0800), then you can create equivalent UTC values and pass them to the Date constructor. That will create a suitable Date object with the required time value and offset based on the system settings.

Given a format of 2015-12-01T05:02:00, then:

```js
function parseAsPST(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], b[1]-1 ,b[2], +b[3] + 8, b[4], b[5]));
}

var d = parseAsPST('2015-12-01T05:02:00');
document.write('ISO 8601: ' + d.toISOString() + '<br>' +
               'Local string: ' + d.toLocaleString());
```

However, if the response is PST then likely you will get PDT when the locality in which the server resides changes to that timezone. Since the string you get doesn't include the time zone, how will you tell whether the string is PST or PDT?